# Display fields based on items in a list in my model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my model I actually have a list of items coming from another model.

I want to display a TextBoxFor(disabled) for each properties of each items in the list, kind of like a cart box.

Here's part of my model:

```
public class ObjOrderInfo
{
    (...)
    public List<ObjOrderDetailInfo> m_ListObjOrderDetail { get; set; }
}
```

and here's part of my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    (...)
    @foreach (var item in Model.m_ListObjOrderDetail)
    {
        (insert code here)
    }
}
```

Basically my other object (ObjOrderDetailInfo) has properties like a quantity, a price, and another object. I would always want to display a textboxfor or a displayfor for each of these properties. But I'm clueless as to how could I do this... can anyone help me on that one?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    (...)
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.m_ListObjOrderDetail.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.m_ListObjOrderDetail[i].SomeProperty)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.m_ListObjOrderDetail[i].SomeOtherProperty)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(
            x => x.m_ListObjOrderDetail[i].YetAnotherProperty, 
            new { @readonly = "readonly" }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this should work:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.m_ListObjOrderDetail)
    {
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item)</li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Although this might work for display purposes, I believe it won't work when you need the user to edit, like the OP describes. You will end up with a bunch of input elements that all have the same name. Doing a regular `for` loop, like Darin shows, properly works with model binding to lists. See [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a View called "ObjOrderDetailInfo.cshtml". This View should be strongly typed against `ObjOrderDetailInfo`, and you'll want to put in the controls to Edit the `ObjOrderDetailInfo` in the View (use the "Edit" scaffold template if you want).

2) Place the above View in the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder.

3) In your View for ObjOrderInfo, do something like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_ListObjOrderDetail)
```